# How to make text-align: center in google app-script (Calendar)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I new one in app-script, and I want just paste and align text using CardService.newTextParagraph()

```
CardService.newTextParagraph()
        .setText(text)
```

I want use something like this

```
CardService.newTextParagraph()
        .setText(text)
        .setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

But its function and enum available only in the Document app.

By default in addon text aligned to the left. I just want to align it in the center.
Have anybody some advice or suggestion, how I can do it?
Thanks

Comment: There is no .setAlignment() method in textParagraph class

Comment: I know it, and it's sad. Do you know some solution how I can do it?

Comment: I think that google wants to maintain control over the styling of the page.

Comment: I understood, thanks for your time, thought maybe someone had same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align text can be used class Class Grid.

docs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/grid

usage -

```js
function buildCard() {
    const cardSection1GridItem = CardService.newGridItem()
        .setTitle('Title')
        .setSubtitle('Subtitle')
        .setTextAlignment(CardService.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
        .setLayout(CardService.GridItemLayout.TEXT_BELOW);

    const cardSectionGrid = CardService.newGrid()
        .setNumColumns(1)
        .setTitle('Grid')
        .addItem(cardSection1GridItem);

    const cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSectionGrid);

    const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
        
    return card;
}
```